# Is it possible to open application using package name on onReceive()?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, package-managers

I'm having a requirement where i will registering few alarm manager to perform specific task and on onReceive() i'm doing the specific task.

As of now this is working only when the task is in background that is not killed.

I'm planning to open a application using package name when the application is not in background on onReceive(). As per my research, it is only possible to open activity from onReceive() but not the application using package name.

If possible could you please shed some light on how to proceed further?

Thank you

Comment: Is the application you want to launch one of your own or a third-party's? Either way, you should consider launching the app through a carefully configured Intent.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, its my own app..

Comment: you can close the app and start a new task and launch your launcher activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try this

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package");
startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

OR

```
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package"));
```

Comment: Thanks i will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

If it is your own app then you can use this

```
Intent intentone = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), "LauncherActivity");
intentone.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intentone);
```

This will work in my case.
let me know if it does for you.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Above case is when the app is till in background right?